# SeismicCube.IndexAtPosition unexpected output

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm not sure what is going wrong here.  It works in some projects, but not in others.  I can't figure out what the difference is between them.  To test the problem, I created a point set with a single point at a position I am sure is inside the cube.  When I call `IndexAtPosition`, I sometimes get obviously wrong answers.  For example, I sometimes get inline or crossline indexes that are negative or way beyond the maximum index.  The z-dimension index also comes back with a very unrealistic answer too.

I am fairly certain that my data is all consistent, i.e. same domain and CRS.  There must be some settings I'm not checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I made a mistake.  One of my data points was in fact outside of the cube area when the cube was rotated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your point is a point like x, y, 1000m in depth
the cube however is probably in the time domain.  So if you try to find a point in the cube you are going to be looking at x,y, 1000Seconds.  This would be VERY far out of range and would give you a crazy number for your k index (super high).  Based on the angle from north your i,j could be crazy too that far away from reality.  You need to have your point in time or some way to convert it from Depth to Time.